# Calculator in C of any length and precision (Real numbers)

Tags: c, linked-list, calculator, arithmetic-expressions

recently at my university, I was asked to write a Calculator in C. Here is a full task:

> Calculator — The program should allow performing the basic mathematical
>   operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) on integer
>   and real numbers of any length and precision.

My idea was to store every single digit in separate "block" of a doubly-linked list. I have managed to do the addition and subtraction without any serious problems, it works just fine using this method. But multiplication and division are a problem. I have no idea how I'm supposed to take care of that. Should I do it also using linked list or there is another better approach? Please give me any ideas! Please keep in mind that this is first semester of my studies so it shouldn't be too complicated. Thanks!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Here is the deal. I write that code for your homework. I will do this after you decorate my lounge .

Comment: It's worth noting that if your calculator only needs to accept decimal-notation numbers (e.g. `1.7`) and the four basic arithmetic operators, you only need to figure out how to represent [rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number), which is significantly easier than representing all [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number).

Comment: show sample input and output. How long are the arithmetic expressions? are parenthesis allowed to change order or operations? how are you using a linked list? If the requirement is to only add/subtract/multiply/divide 2 numbers at a time based on a selection menu, then answer is trivial

Comment: It's a good exercise. Yes, use linked lists. Multiplication should be straightforward. Of course, you need to keep track of where the decimal point is. For division, I would suggest just doing long-division like you learned in grammar school. Then you need to have a way to terminate long fractions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

look into implementing a finite state machine. You can also throw in stack data structure in order to handle the arithmetic for numbers that exceed any data type.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: I don't have enough credit

Answer (score 0):

If you have to implement this yourself then you should do some research on "Arbitrary Precision Arithmatic", or BigNum.  etc.

This link will get you started which describes storing the numbers in arrays.  It also has further links to algorithms you may find useful:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic